# camel-restlet and org.restlet.jee.ext.spring versions conflict?

Tags: apache-camel, restlet

I am trying to create a webapp to deploy on Glassfish 4. 
Following the example at 
[Using the Restlet servlet within a webapp](http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html)

- created maven project
- added dependecies to `pom.xml`
- put servlet config into `web.xml`
- put bean definition into context.xml

My problem is that it doesn't run as webapp under glassfish. With `mvn jetty:run` it runs fine but in glassfish not.

I suspect Spring version conflict between camel-restlet and org.restlet.jee.ext.sprint.

- `camel-restlet v1.13.0+` depends on `spring v3.2.8.RELEASE`
- `org.restlet.jee.ext.sprint v2.2.2` depends on `spring v3.2.6.RELEASE`

earlier version have similar differencies like

- `camel-restlet v1.12.3+` depends on `spring v3.2.5.RELEASE`

So I could not find version of `camel-restlet` and `ext.spring` that would match each other.

How can I make the example from camel.apache.org work under glassfish.

p.s. google and co. did that already. examples from github and other resources tried already.

So. Here is output from the server.log from webapp running in glassfish. As I said same code runs well in jetty.

```
SpringCamelContext     DEBUG Route: RS_RestletDemo >>> EventDrivenConsumerRoute[Endpoint[/demo/(id)?restletMethods=GET] -> Channel[Transform(Simple: Request type : ${header.CamelHttpMethod} and ID : ${header.id})]]
SpringCamelContext     DEBUG Starting consumer (order: 1001) on route: RS_RestletDemo
DefaultManagementAgent DEBUG Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1-1,type=consumers,name=RestletConsumer(0x40cb4833)
RestletConsumer        DEBUG Starting consumer: Consumer[/demo/(id)?restletMethods=GET]
RestletComponent       DEBUG Setting parameters: [] to server: org.restlet.Server@8528a1b
RestletComponent       DEBUG Added server: null:80
RestletComponent       DEBUG Added method based router: org.apache.camel.component.restlet.MethodBasedRouter@62e8f6e1
RestletComponent       DEBUG Attached restlet uriPattern: /demo/{id} method: GET
RestletComponent       DEBUG Attached methodRouter uriPattern: /demo/{id}
RestletComponent       DEBUG Started methodRouter uriPattern: /demo/{id}
SpringCamelContext     INFO  Route: RS_RestletDemo started and consuming from: Endpoint[/demo/(id)?restletMethods=GET]
```

`GET http://localhost:8080/camel-restlet/rs/demo/123`

HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet RestletServlet threw exception
root cause

java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/restlet/ext/servlet/internal/ServletWarClient.<init>(Lorg/restlet/Context;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)V @35: putfield
  Reason:
    Type 'org/restlet/ext/servlet/internal/ServletWarClientHelper' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'org/restlet/engine/connector/ClientHelper'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @35
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/restlet/ext/servlet/internal/ServletWarClient', 'org/restlet/Context', 'javax/servlet/ServletContext' }
    stack: { 'org/restlet/ext/servlet/internal/ServletWarClient', 'org/restlet/ext/servlet/internal/ServletWarClientHelper' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a2b b600 0101 c000 02b7 0003 2ab6 0004
    0000010: b200 05b9 0006 0200 572a bb00 0759 2a2c
    0000020: b700 08b5 0009 b1
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

I tried overriding spring version, excluding expring dependencies in pom.xml etc.. no luck.

**UPDATE**. *FIXED*

A note for people who face similar problem
I fixed this by 
- using `org.restlet.ext.spring v2.1.7` and `camel-restlet v2.13.2`
- moving `org.restlet.ext.spring` to the top
- removing all spring dependencies from `pom.xml`
moved

Now it works as `war` in `glassfish 3,4` and standalone `jetty`
An example of working version can be found at [github](https://github.com/vemod/camel-restlet/tree/f7b3e2530474d4eaae0003482f08c4085e366751)